# Items not showing in folder?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, view, caml

Basically, I have a situation where instead of creating 10 individual document libraries, I've created one and filter each "region" as such by subfolders in the library.

Canada Finance > Document Folder 1, Document Folder 2, etc
US Finance > Documnet Folder 1, Document Fold 2, etc

In each regions page I link to a view, which I've customized to add:

```
<View Name="{guid}" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="CAFIN" Url="/Canada-Finance" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/dlicon.png" Scope="RecursiveAll" >
<Query>
                <Where>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name="FileDirRef"/>
                        <Value Type="Text">/Canada-Finance</Value>
                    </Eq>

                </Where>
            </Query>
```

This works fine to display the specified subfolder, but how can I display the documents in the subfolder? They do not appear in this case, and I cannot figure out how to make them appear. I am using Foundation so I do not have access to CQWP or other great tools that would make this easier to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add after `</Where>`

```
<QueryOptions>
    <ViewAttributes Scope="RecursiveAll" />
</QueryOptions>
```

Reference:
[Need a CAML query to "show all items without folders" in sharepoint list view.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/423afb13-2864-4cc9-8359-f0e9691f096e/need-a-caml-query-to-show-all-items-without-folders-in-sharepoint-list-view?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

Comment: I've used the tag here: <View Name="{guid}" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="CAFIN" Url="/Canada-Finance" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/dlicon.png" Scope="RecursiveAll" >-still no files showing up in the subfolders

Comment: Take a look at 夏至夕陽 answer. I think he has a better idea on that is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to use `<Contains>` but not `<Eq>` in where clause, because in FileDirRef, there is not only "/Canada-Finance", but also have other values, like: `{document library URL}/{Folder Name 1}/xxx`